# Crashlytics: module-relative stack addresses?

Tags: android, crash-reports, crashlytics, google-fabric, google-play-console

We have a shared library which we do not wish to share the symbol names with anything - including Crashlytics.

As such we really want either:
1. The base address at which each .so has been loaded or 
2. Module-relative addresses shown in addition to or instead of absolute addresses in stack traces

Either of those would allow us to produce post-processing tooling (ala addr2line, etc) that turn the crash report into something meaningful without sharing library symbols externally.

Is there some way already to get at this information with Crashlytics? If not, any chance it could be added in the near future? What about the crash reporting via Google Play Console?

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics does not offer a viable solution for this right now. Our symbolication is all or nothing. Thanks!